How to initalize sql.NullString member in struct type?
Given below type, which cannot be changed in existing code:
import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
)

type MyNullString struct {
    sql.NullString
    json.Marshaler
    json.Unmarshaler
}


How to initialize below struct A?
type A struct{
     B MyNullString
}


Trying below syntax:
a := A{
  B: MyNullString{String: "aaa", Valid: true}
}

gives error: unknown field String in struct literal of type MyNullString

How to initialize member B of struct A?
Tried this answer, no luck

Is your intent to make a struct which contains a MyNullString member? Or to make a struct of type MyNullString?

@Schwern struct A contains MyNullString as member. This is also an existing code. Am trying to write test cases, using this code

type MyNullString struct {
    sql.NullString
    json.Marshaler
    json.Unmarshaler
}

That says you have a type MyNullString which is a struct with sql.NullString, json.Marshaler, and json.Unmarshaler embedded members. The struct does not inherit its embedded structs' fields, they might not even be structs. It takes values of that type.
Since the member names were not given, the member names are the names of the type it takes without a namespace.
a := A{
  B: MyNullString{
    NullString: sql.NullString{String: "Foo", Valid: true},
    Marshaler: SomethingThatImplementsMarshal(),
    Unmarshaler: SomethingThatImplementsUnmarshal(),
  }
}


Note: it might make more sense to simply use MyNullString directly rather than define a new struct with just one member.
